# Dovecot not working, apparently not listening to ports 110, 143, 993 or 995

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

My new mailserver with Postfix (3.3.0) and Dovecot (v2.2.33.2) doesn't work yet, since last time I installed a few years ago and now, the configuration changed a lot I noticed, e.g. in Dovecot the protocols are managed in a different way. It is running on Ubuntu 18.04.1 x64.

Now the server is only sending mails, not receiving. There must be some configuration problem but I'm not able to find it.

I tried verbose logging without any strange messages (as far as I could see). Otherwise, 'service dovecot status' gives this alert: `starting up without any protocols` 
Could this be the problem?

netstat -ltnp

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10023         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1038/postgrey --pid
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10024         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1217/amavisd-new (m
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:10025         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2551/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      963/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      937/nginx: master p
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:465             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2551/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      644/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      880/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2551/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      937/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 2a03:b0c0:0:1010::10023 :::*                    LISTEN      1038/postgrey --pid
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10023               :::*                    LISTEN      1038/postgrey --pid
tcp6       0      0 ::1:10024               :::*                    LISTEN      1217/amavisd-new (m
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      937/nginx: master p
tcp6       0      0 :::465                  :::*                    LISTEN      2551/master
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      880/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      2551/master
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      937/nginx: master p
```

ufw status

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
587/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
25/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
465/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
993/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
995/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
123/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
2812/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
110/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
143/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
587/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
25/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
465/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
993/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
995/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
123/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2812/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
110/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
143/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

service dovecot status

```
 dovecot.service - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-08-10 16:28:55 CEST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:dovecot(1)
           http://wiki2.dovecot.org/
 Main PID: 3122 (dovecot)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dovecot.service
           ├─3122 /usr/sbin/dovecot -F
           ├─3132 dovecot/anvil
           ├─3133 dovecot/log
           └─3136 dovecot/config

Aug 10 16:28:55 domain.tld systemd[1]: Started Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server.
Aug 10 16:28:55 domain.tld dovecot[3122]: master: Dovecot v2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This entry in the log—where it says “starting up without any protocols”—is the big clue:

```
Aug 10 16:28:55 domain.tld dovecot[3122]: master: Dovecot v2.2.33.2 (d6601f4ec) starting up without any protocols (core dumps disabled)
```

It seems like Dovecot isn’t aware of any protocols being set on your install so it’s just starting up as-is.

And according [to this comment to an answer on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/440669/dovecot-starting-and-running-but-not-listening-on-any-port/440691#comment853500_440691):

> On Debian there is a `!include_try /usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/*.protocol` setting. These protocols are enabled automatically by an installation of corresponding packages, `dovecot-pop3d` for example.

So that tells me that you need to install the `dovecot-pop3d` package and [this is confirmed here on the official Ubuntu page for Dovecot that states](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot):

> The installation is extremely simple, just install the following packages:
>
> 1. dovecot-imapd
> 2. dovecot-pop3d
>
> For example, using apt-get:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
> ```

So I recommend that you just go ahead and install those packages like this:

```
sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
```

Pretty sure after you do that and then check the `/usr/share/dovecot/protocols.d/` directory you will see some `.protocol` files in there. Just restart Dovecot after doing that and you should be good.